# Maven mojo - prevent execution on project in current working directory?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

I'm writing a Maven plugin and would like to prevent it running on the project in the current working directory. The plugin is designed to run on an artifactId (or list of artifactIds) specified by the user, which may not be the artifact in the current working directory.

I find Maven always starts interrogating the project in the working directory, creating log messages which will confuse users of my plugin.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: What do you mean by saying "prevent"? You don't want user to launch your plugin in the directory with maven project? If so, why?

Comment: I knew someone would ask that! I'm fine with the user launching the plugin in a directory with a project in it, but I don't want the plugin to build the project (or do anything with it). My plugin is a tool for downloading sources for a project specified with -DartifactId. I don't want to confuse the user by Maven trying to execute anything on the project in the current working directory

Answer (score 0):

Use `@requiresProject false` annotation for your mojo.

Comment: I already have  @requiresProject false   --unfortunately this doesn't prevent Maven from scanning and finding the project in the working directory

Comment: @ChrisBeach Hm, I'm not sure you can do anything about that. Try to launch dependency plugin, goal `get`, for example, in the directory with maven project. It automatically scans this project.